# Custom listView shows less items in random order

Tags: android, listview

I have made a custom inflated listView for my android app and I have a problem with getView() method.

```
public class BinderData extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList targetList;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private Activity nikola;
    private Context context;

    private static ArrayList genres = new ArrayList();

    public BinderData(Activity act, List<Genre> map) {
        targetList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i<map.size(); i++){
            Genre genre = map.get(i);
            targetList.add(genre);
            ArrayList<Artist> aList = genre.getArtists();
            for (int j = 0; j<aList.size(); j++){
                targetList.add(aList.get(j));
            }
        }
        this.nikola = act;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

And here is my getView() method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null){
            ViewableItem item = (ViewableItem)targetList.get(position);
            if (item.isTypeOf().equalsIgnoreCase("genre")){
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, null);
                holder = new GenreViewHolder();
                ((GenreViewHolder)holder).textViewGenreTitle = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryTitle);
                String s = ((Genre)item).getTitle();
                holder.setTitle(s);
            }else{
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                holder = new ArtistViewHolder();
                ((ArtistViewHolder)holder).textViewArtistName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthorNameHome);
                String s = ((Artist)item).getArtist();
                holder.setArtistName(s);
            }
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        return vi;
    }
```

I have 2 type of layouts for my list. One is for category title and the other one is for the items under that category.

http://imgur.com/xbPfGTi - here is the picture

I have made the targetList filled with data I need to show in my listView. (in the constructor)
And there is the problem!
The artists in the list keep repeating and the categories are not in the right place.

Have any ideas?

Comment: what is your exact problem ?

Comment: You see in the picture... It seems like only 5 or 6 views are inflated.
Other artist (60 of them) are not shown at all... 
But if I erase this ---if (convertView == null)--- everything works fine.
Only problem there is memory leakage which will make my app stop after a while

Comment: And one more thing... that POP category should not be doubled. The position of that row is wrong and one of the should not be pop, it should be rock or folk or something else from mu targetList

Comment: first of all, if your adapter adapt the 60 artists so the listview will show them all by scrolling , if ur list view shows 5 or 6 artists so it will show them all, second for the POP , you have to check your xml file, do you have just one textview in int?

Comment: Everything is fine with the xml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that you are not binding your data to your rows when `convertView != null`, instead you are returning the `convertView` that is recycled to you, which is why you see the same repeated data.

You need to bind data to your row's `View`s for every row, according to the data type, like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View row;
    boolean isGenreRow = getItemViewType(position) == GENRE_ROW;

    // Inflate views if this is a new row
    if (convertView == null) {
        // Get the right type of view depending on the type of data
        if (isGenreRow) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, null);
            holder = new GenreViewHolder();
            ((GenreViewHolder) holder).textViewGenreTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategoryTitle);
        }
        else {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            holder = new ArtistViewHolder();
            ((ArtistViewHolder) holder).textViewArtistName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthorNameHome);
        }
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    // Otherwise, use the recycled row
    else {
        row = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    // Bind data to views, depending on data type
    ViewableItem item = (ViewableItem) targetList.get(position);
    if (isGenreRow) {
        ((GenreViewHolder) holder).setTitle(((Genre) item).getTitle());
    }
    else {
        ((ArtistViewHolder) holder).setArtistName(((Artist) item).getArtist());
    }

    return row;
}
```

You also must override a few other methods to let the `BaseAdapter` know that there is more than one data type, so it knows how to recycle the row's `View`s.

```
private static final int GENRE_ROW = 0;
private static final int ARTIST_ROW = 1;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Return the row type at the position
    ViewableItem item = (ViewableItem) targetList.get(position);
    return item.isTypeOf().equalsIgnoreCase("genre") ? GENRE_ROW : ARTIST_ROW;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // Return the number of row types there are
    return 2;
}
```

You should be able to copy and paste this solution in, assuming I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: I think I love YOU!!! : ) <3
I have been figuring this out for couple of hours... And I need to say that you made my day!
Thank you very much!
Everything works perfectly... 

Only one more question...
Will I be able to define onClickListeners on the same place where I am binding data to my views?

Comment: Awesome, glad I didn't make any mistakes :). And yes, you can add click listeners in the area where you bind your data to the views (I have done this before).